# How to get changing variable values into one fixed variable out of for loop?

Tags: python, string, function, variables, for-loop

The question seems very confusing I know but hear me out. My function generates 9 random 5 letter words and are put into a grid. The grid is then printed out after being assigned to the varaible "grid1". The problem is that words in grid form can only be printed in the for loop, not outside of it as can be seen:

```
def function():

    random_words = [''.join(random.sample(ascii_letters, 5)) for i in range(20)]

    # select 9 from the random words and make grid
    words = random.sample(random_words, 9)

function()
```

result:

```
ShVJG QPdpH VjkWE
CJlTB ktcna Vqgvx
cLnuB zQMGZ JvZrc

cLnuB zQMGZ JvZrc
```

I need the words in grid form in one variable when I print it out of the loop so I can use that variable containing the words in grid form somewhere else, like in a toplevel window in tkinter(use the grid variable as a label in it etc etc.). But the thing is that when the varaaible is  printed out of the loop, only the last grid row prints(because of the variable changing in the loop). How can I get the word grid from the for loop, assign it to a variable, and print the variable outside of the loop, making sure all 3 rows print out not just the last row???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grid1 = '\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in grid)
```